# Why am I getting an empty array json response from web api?

Tags: c#, httpclient, webapi

I have a simple web api project which I am trying to call using an HttpClient(trying to fetch products from database Table).
I get a result of an empty array [] although I have stored data in my Database(sqlServer).

API:

Model:
public partial class Products
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Category { get; set; }
public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

Controller:
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
private TestAPIContext db = new TestAPIContext();

```
    // GET: api/Products
    [ResponseType(typeof(Products))]
    public IQueryable<Products> GetProducts()
    {
        return db.Products;
    }

    // GET: api/Products/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Products))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetProduct(int id)
    {
        Products product = await db.Products.FindAsync(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(product);
    }

    // PUT: api/Products/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutProduct(int id, Products product)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != product.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!ProductExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST: api/Products
    [ResponseType(typeof(Products))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostProduct(Products product)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Products.Add(product);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = product.Id }, product);
    }

    // DELETE: api/Products/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Products))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DeleteProduct(int id)
    {
        Products product = await db.Products.FindAsync(id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Products.Remove(product);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok(product);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool ProductExists(int id)
    {
        return db.Products.Count(e => e.Id == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

HttpClient:

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8090/");

```
        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Products").Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var products = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            grvProducts.DataSource = products;

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Code" + 
            response.StatusCode + " : Message - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
        }
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you try the HTTP request in a browser?

Comment: I get the following: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<ArrayOfProducts xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/TestAPI.Models"/>

Comment: I have also checked it with Postman too. I get [] for a response

Comment: The problem is server side. What is the techno? ASP.NET Core?

Comment: I use .NetFrameWork 4.8 with VS2013

Comment: And the web framework?

Comment: web api2 with entity framework 6

Answer (score 0):

create action

```
    [Route("~/api/getallproducts")]
    public IEnumerable<Products> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return  db.Products.ToArray();
    }
```

and fix the request

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/getallProducts").Result;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
var stringData = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(stringData);
 grvProducts.DataSource = products;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't work. I tried it.

Comment: @AlexandrosAngelopoulos I updated my code, it should be working now

Comment: Thank you again Serge but it doesn't work. Still getting an empty array as result both with my client code and using Postman... I think the client works ok...it seems to be a server-side problem. It just won't return the data for some reason